# Why do I get duplicate data when import CSV file into MySQL with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv, import

When submit button clicked, I get duplicate date in MySQL database, which means a single row in CSV file is inserted twice and get identical records in database.

My php code goes here.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if( $_FILES['file']['name']){
    $filename = explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name']);
    if ($filename[1] == 'csv'){
        $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"r");
        if($_POST['dataType']=='aType'){
            while ($data = fgetcsv($handle)){
                $item0 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[0]);
                $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[1]);
                $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[2]);
                $item3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[3]);
                $sql = "insert into `table_XX`(`Column_A`,`Column_B`,`Column_C`,`Column_D`) VALUES ('$item0','$item1','$item2','$item3')";
                mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            }
            if(!(mysqli_query($con,$sql))) echo "something is wrong!";
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}
```

}

My Html code goes here.

```
<form method="post" action="import.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <select name="dataType" class="form-control">
     <option selected="selected">pls select data</option>
     <option>aType</option>
  </select>
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

What's wrong with my code? Thanks.

---

Edit:

Later I know that this line of code cause this mistake.

```
if(!(mysqli_query($con,$sql))) echo "something is wrong!"
```

However, it is a bad habit to use code like this to check our query?

```
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
```

---

By the way, how can I use a Array to store the value from

```
mysqli_real_escape_string
```

instead of using this x4

```
$item0 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[0]);
$item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[1]);
$item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[2]);
$item3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[3]);
```

Comment: Are you sure that your php code is not called up twice?

Comment: well I have just learn a little about file with php code, so might have a lot of mistakes, but I just cannot find them.@Fabian Picone

Comment: Is your code in a function? Maybe the function is called up twice. Can you show more from your code?

Comment: emm,actually I found this **if(!(mysqli_query($con,$sql)))  echo "something is wrong!"**. this code was right before **fclose($handle)** ..may be that's the reason  the mysqli_query is called up twice @Fabian Picone

Comment: Could your tell me how to use an  array to store the value from 
 mysqli_real_escape_string, I know I can use a loop to do with it, but fail 
 again and again, it's so frustrating.@Fabian Picone

Comment: You found something in between your lines? So your code shown up here is not the code you really have. Its difficult to help that way, can you show more real code please? Well the loop problem is another problem. Step by step. Its too unreadable if i write a loop solution in this comment line. And its wrong when i post it as answer because its not the answer of your primary question.

Comment: And if you call `mysqli_query()` twice in `while` then yes, thats the reason why you get double insertions. Also if `mysqli_query()` is in an `if` itself.

Comment: @Fabian Picone I have edited the question and update the code, the very line I have mention in the comment  has been posted, and I try to delete that line and successfully removed the duplicate records ; ) My original code is too lengthy to read, so I simplified them. So it is the real reason to cause that problem, only because I put `mysqli_query` in `if()`??

Comment: The reason is because `mysqli_query()` is called twice. Also in `if()` it executes itself! If you want to check the result of `mysqli_query()` safe it in an variable like `$queryResult = mysqli_query()` and then `if($queryResult)`.

Comment: @Fabian Picone you may post your answer and I will accept it, for you offer so much help. Grateful !

Comment: I added the array solution for you. Please accept my answer for the solving the double-insert problem. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because `mysqli_query()` is called twice. Also in `if()` it executes itself! If you want to check the result of `mysqli_query()` safe it in an variable like `$queryResult = mysqli_query()` and then `if($queryResult)`.

Replace `mysqli_query($con,$sql);` with

```
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    echo "something is wrong!";
}
```

And Remove: `if(!(mysqli_query($con,$sql))) echo "something is wrong!";`

**ADDITION** Array solution

Replace

```
$item0 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[0]);
$item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[1]);
$item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[2]);
$item3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[3]);
```

with (not tested)

```
function escapeArray(array $data) {
    foreach($data as $i => $item) {
        $data[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($item);
    }
    return $data;
}

$data = escapeArray($data);
```

Then either do `VALUES (" . $data[0] . "," . $data[1] . ", " . $data[2] . "," . $data[3] . ")`

or

`VALUES (" . implode(',', $data) . ")`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Very kind of you !